# .NET caching tool

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

Why would you use a third-party caching tool and which one would you rcommend for ASP.NET?

Comment: There are a couple types of Caching and asp has built in Caching, what type of caching are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used Velocity but find it very raw and relocated our website on memcached - very stable cache. I vote for memcached http://www.danga.com/memcached/.

Comment: How is different than inbuit API for caching in .net 2.0?

Comment: "inbuit API" What does it means ?

Comment: @Brijesh Mishra: I think "the built-in API" was meant. In full: "How is that different from the built-in API for caching in .NET 2.0?"